# HTML <input> for inches / dimensional values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project where user input will be based in inches+fractions of inches.

Currently, we use a method with two  fields, one populated with whole integer values, the other populated with fractional values (1/16, 1/8, 3/16, etc ... )

From a UI standpoint, this feels a little sloppy, and I'm wondering if there is a javascript/jQuery solution others have used that allows the user to input dimensional sizes.

Looking at new input types provided by HTML5, it seems like this type of input would be quite useful, yet it hasn't been considered.

Comment: There isn't. You'll have to do some clever presentation of multiple inputs. With a little styling I'm sure it can be fairly clean. Metric FTW.

Comment: what about the user inputting a decimal and you convert it to a fraction? Is that acceptable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411343/allow-special-characters-fractions-in-html5-number-input

Comment: @Ronnie, quick, what's the decimal equivalent of 15/32? :P

Comment: @isherwood lol, I know what you mean, but we don't know the whole story of this project. Maybe the user has the decimal form already

Comment: You can make your own custom input (use Div and a hidden text input and capture the focus, keyboard and write your own regex to parse it)

Comment: Ultimately the value needs to be represented as a fraction, but the input could be either method. Traditionally, the value would be represented as a fraction, though.

Comment: why not just use one field and allow them to type something like `1 3/4` for example

Comment: @Ronnie That would probably be awkward in our case, as there are only specific allowed values and that would leave the user guessing which values would validate as okay (or we could do rounding up/down to a valid value I suppose).

This was kind of a shot-in-the-dark question to see if there was already some tools out there (I didn't find much).

Comment: yeah, I've been searching...I cannot find anything that will output a fraction like `¼` I could probably build something that does do that with some time

Comment: if you have `only specific allowed values` then why not just use a combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

Started writing a JSFiddle for this, but the actual implementation was taking a bit more time than I had to give. My apologies for doing this in pseudocode. Sorry again. Here's what I'd do.

```
input.addEventListener('input', function(event){

  var current_value, separator, formatted_length, output;

  current_value = event.target.value;
  output = document.getElementById('formatted_length');

  // determine input format

    if( current_value.indexOf(".") > -1 ){ separator = 'decimal'; }
    else if( current_value.indexOf("'") > -1 ){ separator = 'inch'; }
    else if( current_value.indexOf("/") > -1 || current_value.indexOf("\\") > -1 ){ 
        separator = 'fraction'; 
    }
    else{ separator = "none"; }

 // write individual handler for each type
 // deal with the weird nuances of each format in a defined code block
 // format the input value into your preferred output value
 // save it to formatted_length

    switch( separator ){

        case 'decimal':
        // handle decimal input formatting here
        break;

        case 'inch':
        // handle inch input formatting here
        break;

        case 'fraction':
        // handle fraction input formatting here
        break;

        case 'none': // fall-through, just in case. no pun intended.
        default:
        // handle unidentified formatting here
        // i'd recommend converting value to integer and throwing an error it fails
        break;
    }

 // output formatted value to the UI
    output.innerHTML = formatted_length;
});
```

Seeing as I failed pretty much every math class I've taken, I don't trust myself to write code to handle parsing through random user input and making sense of it to get imperial or metric formats correctly as well as the variants of them users may try. It's not straightforward in the least.

If you think it's such a simple problem, try processing this timestamp and outputting a universally understood date from this: 01/10/01

Anyways, so sorry for not actually providing a fully working example, but it will take much more work than you'd think. If you CAN do this, please create an open-source library for handling this. Something like moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Pretty soon you'll be able to do something like this (only working in FF nightly right now):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en_US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>    
    <input is="measurement-field" denominator="16" type="number" />

    <script>
      class MeasurementField extends HTMLInputElement {
        constructor() {
          super();

          this.setStep();
        }

        get denominator() {
          return this.getAttribute('denominator')
        }

        set denominator(val) {
          if(val) {
            this.setAttribute('denominator', val)
          } else {
            this.removeAttribute('denominator')
          }
        }

        attributeChangedCallback(e) {
          this.setStep();
        }

        setStep() {
          if (this.denominator) {
            this.step = (1 / this.denominator)
          } else {
            this.step = 1
          }
        }
      }

      if (window.customElements !== undefined) {
        customElements.define('measurement-field', MeasurementField, { extends: "input" });
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep checking the status in Chromium here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648828&desc=4